# Is it possible to set event.isTrusted to true in JEST unit tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, events, dom-events, readonly

I am working with **JavaScript** events. As per the following MDN article, the event object has a flag called `isTrusted`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

I have written a code which differentiates user events (triggered as a result of an actual user action) from programmatic events (triggered as a result of `element.dispatchEvent(...)`. I cannot show the entire code but it goes something like below:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.isTrusted) {
    // ... client code follows
    // somewhere in the code I am dispatching another custom event on body element
    document.body.dispatchEvent(...);
  }
});
```

I am trying to **unit test** this code in `JEST` (a popular unit testing library). Unfortunately we cannot simulate real click events since it's an automated code that does it for you. The the flag `isTrusted` is always set to `false` in JEST, thereby restricting me to test the client code.

I cannot change the value of `isTrusted` directly since it is a read only property. I am looking for ways where I can mock the event and set the `isTrusted` flag to `true`.

---

*Edit:* Added the test code:

```js
describe('Event.isTrusted', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    document.body.dispatchEvent = jest.fn();
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.id = 'btn';
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  });
  ...
  it('should allow user events', () => {
    const event = new MouseEvent('click', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancellable: true
    });
    document.getElementById('btn').dispatchEvent(event);
    expect(document.body.dispatchEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Once again this is just a gist. I cannot show the client code. I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you show the test code?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I have added the unit test code in the question

Comment: Do you really have to go the `dispatchEvent` way? Can't you just call the callback with a simple mocked object? Setting the `isTrusted` to a true Event object is impossible, so you'd have to overwrite the whole EventTarget.dispatchEvent code with the addEventListeners etc...

Comment: Yes I can do that, and currently I have taken the approach. But that doesn't answer my question if there is really a way to modify the event object and set ``isTrusted`` to ``true`` which is readonly property. What if I am testing a code where I don't have access to listener, and I am actually reliant on it for my code to work. I mean I am just giving an example. I know I can independently test the other part of code but you got the point. There can be scenarios.

Comment: *"Setting the isTrusted [of] a true Event object is impossible [...]"*

Answer (score 1):

It is possible!

```
describe('Event.isTrusted', () => {

  class CustomMouseEvent {
    isTrusted = true;
    // add the bubbles and cancellation here if needed
  }

  beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(global, 'MouseEvent', {
       value: CustomMouseEvent,
    });

    document.body.dispatchEvent = jest.fn();
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.id = 'btn';
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  });
  ...
  it('should allow user events', () => {
    const event = new CustomMouseEvent();
    document.getElementById('btn').dispatchEvent(event);
    expect(document.body.dispatchEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: For me, it shows error. It says No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 1, '(event: Event): boolean', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'CustomMouseEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Event'